# UserControl throws System.ArgumentException

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Hi i'm using an userControl it works fine  but when i try to use it  for second time it throws the next exception

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
Additional information: The parameter is incorrect.**

Here's my code

XAML

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TextBlock x:Name="tb1" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Foreground="Black" Opacity="0.7" Margin="1,3,0,0" Text="{Binding Text,ElementName=me}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="tb2" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Foreground="Black" Opacity="0.7" Margin="1,3,0,0" Text="{Binding Text,ElementName=tb1}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  />
    <TextBlock x:Name="tb3" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Foreground="Black" Opacity="0.7" Margin="1,3,0,0" Text="{Binding Text,ElementName=tb1}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="tb4" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Foreground="Black" Opacity="0.7" Margin="1,3,0,0" Text="{Binding Text,ElementName=tb1}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="tb5" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Foreground="Black" Opacity="0.7" Margin="1,3,0,0" Text="{Binding Text,ElementName=tb1}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="tb6" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Foreground="Black" Opacity="0.7" Margin="1,3,0,0" Text="{Binding Text,ElementName=tb1}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="tb7" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Foreground="Black" Opacity="0.7" Margin="1,3,0,0" Text="{Binding Text,ElementName=tb1}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="tb8" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Foreground="White"  Text="{Binding Text,ElementName=tb1}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
  </Grid>
```

C#

```
  public partial class DropShadowTextBlock : UserControl
  {
    public DropShadowTextBlock()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public SolidColorBrush Foreground
    {
        get { return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(ForegroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ForegroundProperty,value);}
    }


    public static void ForegroundPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DropShadowTextBlock control = sender as DropShadowTextBlock;
        if (control != null)
        {
            control.tb8.Foreground = e.NewValue as SolidColorBrush;
        }

    }
   public static void TextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
            var control = sender as DropShadowTextBlock;
            if (control.tb1 != null)
            control.tb1.Text = e.NewValue.ToString();
   }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(DropShadowTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(TextPropertyChanged)));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ForegroundProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Foreground", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(DropShadowTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(ForegroundPropertyChanged)));

  }
}
```

And finally here's how i use the userControl

```
        public void dibujarTexto(String text)
        {
          DropShadowTextBlock textblockTop = new DropShadowTextBlock();
          textblockTop.Text = text;
          textblockTop.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
          textblockTop.Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
          migrid.Children.Add(textblockTop); //this is a grid control
        }
```

I've been sharing and i found  that the control names must be unique so i'm using the Guid class to get random names  but doesn't work

Please if somebody could help me.

Thanks best regards.

Comment: Which line it happens ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. I just add a new name to my grid and now it works fine :D

```
 public void dibujarTexto(String text)
    {
      DropShadowTextBlock textblockTop = new DropShadowTextBlock();
      textblockTop.Text = text;
      textblockTop.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
      textblockTop.Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
      migrid.Name= Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
      migrid.Children.Add(textblockTop); //this is a grid control
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, names of controls are unique, but have you specified id of your user control (in xaml code at the top)? If so, delete this line.